# coloring divs onclick after button pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have the following:

```js
$(function() {
  var b = $("#btn");
  var a = $(".a");
  var c = $(".c");
  var e = $(".e");
  var g = $(".g");

  b.click(function() {
    a.click(function() {
      var cls = this.className;
      var clss = cls.slice(-1);

      switch (clss) {
        case "c":
          $(this).css({
            "background-color": "red"
          });
          break;
        case "e":
          $(this).css({
            "background-color": "green"
          });
          break;
        case "g":
          $(this).css({
            "background-color": "blue"
          });
          break;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.a {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="a c">1</div>
<div class="a c">2</div>
<div class="a e">3</div>
<div class="a e">4</div>
<div class="a g">5</div>
<div class="a g">6</div>
<input type="button" value="button" id="btn">
```

This code is suppose to do the following:
When clicking in `.a`, after you have clicked `#btn`, it should grab the second variable and color:

- `.c` to red
- `.e` to green
- `.g` to blue

But that is not happening at all. Please help me understand and solve my code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working as you expected , the only problem is you are missing jQuery library in your snippet

```js
$(function() {
  var b = $("#btn");
  var a = $(".a");

  function color() {

  }
  b.click(function() {
    a.click(function() {
      var cls = this.className;
      var clss = cls.slice(-1);

      switch (clss) {
        case "c":
          $(this).css({
            "background-color": "red"
          });
          break;
        case "e":
          $(this).css({
            "background-color": "green"
          });
          break;
        case "g":
          $(this).css({
            "background-color": "blue"
          });
          break;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.a {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a c">1</div>
<div class="a c">2</div>
<div class="a e">3</div>
<div class="a e">4</div>
<div class="a g">5</div>
<div class="a g">6</div>
<input type="button" value="button" id="btn">
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you added the `var a = $(".a,.e,.e,.g");`? I don't quite understand

Comment: When using this code, I was working with it in Codepen. Codepen have libraries "pre-installed".